# Best practices for pushing objects through DevOps?

Tags: record-type, field-update, field-level-security, component, devopscenter

We are using DevOps to push changes from sandboxes through to Production.

Recently, I attempted to deploy some significant changes to an object.  This includes:

- Creation of record types
- New fields
- Renaming existing fields
- Creation of records
- Validation rules for fields

When introduced to DevOps, I was informed that anything that was recently worked on would become available on the list of items available to be pushed, but I found that this was not the case for objects.  I manually went into the Component List and selected Object, Record Types, and Fields (I looked at the "Validation Rules" component and it was empty).  Additionally, when the changes were deployed some "ListView" records were automatically included.

<s>Page layouts is not available on the list of Components.</s>
(Edit: The component related to page layouts is titled simply "Layouts").

I've read about individuals who say that DevOps did not recognize any changes to field names or page layouts.
I found that the record types did not correctly deploy and had to be reconstructed.  Fields that had default field access suddenly were unavailable (should I have included Sharing Rules in the set?).  And there seemed to be no way to push records that were created in the sandbox into production.

Since some files are automatically added (List View) and some files seem to be ignored (changes in FieldsSet), what are best practices for pushing an Object through production?

What components are necessary to be included for everything to go through appropriately?  Are there certain things I just cannot expect to be able to push?

Thanks.

Comment: N.B. while SFDC DevOps Center is freely available, it is new and vendor tools like Gearset, Copado, etc are more mature